# Does Serilog allow delete of live log file and does it have category name

Tags: serilog

We have been using NLog and started looking at Serilog.
We delete the existing log file when looking at issues in the
field. This allows us to minimize what is in a log file in
order to understand the issue.

Using Serilog, I tried deleting the live log file and got an exception the log was in use by an application.

Does Serilog support allowing the delete of a live log file.
We do not need to recreate the file.

My other issue is support for cateories. In NLog we create logger that has a string category name, and the category name is output to the log file. Does Serilog support this?

Comment: Serilog.Sinks.Map to route to multipe inner loggers based on content of messages. File sink has shared and non shared modes which influences file locking (the readme or docs cover that IIRC).